# How is it possible to assign in list values that I can use as reference and increase or decrease accordingly

Tags: python-3.x, list

Example:

```
abc = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

a should have the value 2, b 4 and c 7

How could I add this value to each of those and adjust them accordingly? 
My goal is to make something that uses first the letter with the highest count and then goes lower and each time a letter is used correctly it should increase the value +1
Thank you in advance.

Comment: use dictionary abc = {'a':2,'b':4,'c':7}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a dictionary and increment the values up or down:

```
d = {'a':2,'b':4,'c':7}

# more code

d['a'] += 1

print(d)
# {'a':3,'b':4,'c':7}

# more code

d['c'] -= 1
print(d)
# {'a':3,'b':4,'c':6}
```